# how to create dict to query as example

Tags: python, loops, sqlalchemy

i have a Monster database with columns containing monster information like monster_name, monster_lvl, kill_date on database

```
monster_name | monster_lvl | kill_date
x              2 lvl          today
y              2 lvl          today
x              3 lvl          today
y              3 lvl          today
y              3 lvl          today
```

i have query like this on sqlalchemy:

```
date_filter_by_today=datetime(datetime.today().year,datetime.today().month,datetime.today().day)
monster = Monster.query.filter(Monster.date >= date_filter_by_today).all()
```

i want to create how many monster records from a monster name and from what level but can't.

for example :

dict = {x:{2 lvl : 1 , 3 lvl : 1 }, y : {2 lvl : 1 , 3 lvl : 2 }}

and when i tried ;

```
monster_counter = Counter([i.monster_name for i in monster])
```

it just return ;

{x:2 , y : 3}

and when i tried ;

```
monster_counter = Counter(i.monster_lvl for in [i.monster_name for i in monster])
```

it just return error because `[i.monster_name for i in monster]` is list and there is no i's extension monster_lvl.

Comment: what have you tried? You've shown you're getting back the `monster` data, but what have you tried to get it into the desired dictionary format?

Comment: yes , i want to create dictionary how many monster records from a monster name and from what level

Comment: sure, so, you've tried looping through the rows returned, something like `for row in monster: ...`? Update your question to include what you've tried and how they didn't work.

Comment: i wrote my trials, i can count names but i can't count first levels than names.

Comment: Ok, so, you know about `Counter`, since you've got a more complicated problem than what `Counter` can do you need to know what it is doing: `counter = {}; for i in monster: if i in counter: counter[i] += 1; else: counter[i] = 1`

Comment: You need to take what it is doing and go one level further, because you want a dictionary that's two levels deep.

Comment: Or you could split your data so you ran a counter only on the `x`s then you ran a counter only on the `y`s and then you put those two sets of results into a dictionary

Comment: thank you , it was helpful , now i understand how can i handle with this data and loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could implement this with a list of dicts as your input (as opposed to the objects that you have). First find all the unique `monster_name` values (using a set) and then iterate over them, counting the `monster_lvl` values:

```
monster = [
           {'monster_name' : 'x', 'monster_lvl' : '2 lvl', 'kill_date' : 'today' },
           {'monster_name' : 'y', 'monster_lvl' : '2 lvl', 'kill_date' : 'today' },
           {'monster_name' : 'x', 'monster_lvl' : '3 lvl', 'kill_date' : 'today' },
           {'monster_name' : 'y', 'monster_lvl' : '3 lvl', 'kill_date' : 'today' },
           {'monster_name' : 'y', 'monster_lvl' : '3 lvl', 'kill_date' : 'today' }
           ]
from collections import Counter

monster_names = set(m['monster_name'] for m in monster)
monster_counter = { n : Counter(m['monster_lvl'] for m in monster if m['monster_name'] == n) for n in monster_names }
print(monster_counter)
```

Output:

```
{
 'x': Counter({'2 lvl': 1, '3 lvl': 1}),
 'y': Counter({'3 lvl': 2, '2 lvl': 1})
}
```

For your objects just replace `m['monster_name']` with `m.monster_name` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fetching all the rows from the database, you can get the database to do some of the work by aggregating the rows using [GROUP BY](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm).  In this case we want to group rows by name and level, and get the count of the rows in each grouping.

```python
import sqlalchemy as sa

qry = (session.query(Monster.monster_name,
                     Monster.monster_lvl,
                     sa.func.count(Monster.monster_lvl))
              .filter(Monster.date >= date_filter_by_today)
              .group_by(Monster.monster_name, Monster.monster_lvl)
              .order_by(Monster.monster_name, Monster.monster_lvl))

for name, level, count in qry.all():
      print(f'name: {name} level: {level} count: {count}')
```

Output:

```
name: x level: 2 lvl count: 1
name: x level: 3 lvl count: 1
name: y level: 2 lvl count: 1
name: y level: 3 lvl count: 2
```

Nick's answer shows how to get values into a dictionary, but here's another way, using the results from the group by query:

```python
import collections

counter = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for name, level, count in qry.all():
    counter[name].update({level: count})
print(counter)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'x': {'2 lvl': 1, '3 lvl': 1}, 'y': {'2 lvl': 1, '3 lvl': 2}})
```

Comment: i think i should solve this issue on query side , it looks like more useful.